# How to convert switch statement to if else statement for java

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

a and b are both int variables.

```
switch (a) {
    case 0: b ++; break;
    case 1:
    case -2: b *= 2; break;
    case 4: b = 10 * a;
    default: b *= a;
}
```

How would I write this as a if else statement in as simple of a manner as possible? Coding in Java.

Comment: Which language? And why?!

Comment: Each 'case' is an option for a, so change those to if (a == 0) eg. Then put b's assignment in the Then.

Comment: The language cannot be C# because in that language `case 4` and `default` each have switch sections whose endpoints are reachable. I guess it could be C++ in which "fall through" is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

In `c++`

```
    if(a == 0)
      {
       ...
      }
    else if(a == 1)
      {
       ....
      }
    ...
    /* continues to default case, default follows */
     else
      {
       //default parameters
      }
```

Comment: This doesn't cover fall-through, however.